# Why does the preprocessor skip a file based on its "modifed date"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, include, g++, c-preprocessor

This is the simplest example I can make that illustrates the problem I am having.

We have a structure of files as followed:

```
.
├── main.cpp
├── root
│   ├── A
│   │   └── same.hpp
│   ├── A.hpp
│   ├── B
│   │   └── same.hpp
│   └── B.hpp
└── root.hpp
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "root.hpp"
int main(){}
```

**root.hpp:**

```
#pragma once
namespace root{
    #include "root/A.hpp"
    using namespace A;

    #include "root/B.hpp"
    using namespace B;
}
```

**A.hpp:**

```
#pragma once
namespace A{
    #include "A/same.hpp"
    using namespace same;
}
```

**B.hpp:**

```
#pragma once
namespace B{
    #include "B/same.hpp"
    using namespace same;
}
```

**both the same.hpp files:**

```
#pragma once
namespace same{}
```

---

After the preprocessing of main.cpp, we would expect the source code to be:

```
namespace root{
    namespace A{
        namespace same{}
        using namespace same;
    }
    using namespace A;

    namespace B{
        namespace same{}
        using namespace same;
    }
    using namespace B;
}
int main(){}
```

However, the actual output after running `g++ -std=c++11 -P -E main.cpp` has the second deceleration of the "same" namespace missing:

```
namespace root{
    namespace A{
        namespace same{}
        using namespace same;
    }
    using namespace A;

    namespace B{
        //...      <- where did it go?
        using namespace same;
    }
    using namespace B;
}
int main(){}
```

---

More interestingly, when I run the *touch* command on B's same.hpp file, and re-run the command on main.cpp, it works as expected(as in the output matches what we originally expected).  This leaves me to believe that the file was skipped for a reason related to its modification date.
Any insight on why this is happening?

Comment: I recall seeing something about `#pragma once` using the file's name to determine whether it should be skipped, so that would explain why the line is missing. I don't know how modification date factors into it, though. I'd try using include guards and have separate symbols for your `A/same.hpp` and `B/same.hpp` files.

Comment: My money is that your `#pragma once` is using the filename rather than the pathname and thus gets fooled by 2 files with the same name.

Comment: Maybe related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52566

Comment: On many modern filesystems, `A/same.hpp` and `B/same.hpp` might be two names for the same file. What's a compiler to do?

Comment: @MSalters Check to see if they have the same inode, or check to see if they are symbolically/hard linked? I suppose you're right though. If it's just parsing text, it wouldn't know to evade the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by outputting a unique comment in the similar looking files.